# Remove if the consecutive value appears at end in the group id

Tags: r, dplyr

I try to filter the group id which has at least two **yes** consecutively for the b column but it should be followed by at least one value in the column. I want to remove if the consecutive **b==yes** appears at end of b for the group id. The group id must start at first **yes**. for example in id 2, the first row must discard as its y value starts with **no** before two consecutive **yes**.

```r
data<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,1, 1,2,2,2,3,3,3, 3,4,4,4, 5,5,5,5), a=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2),
b=c("yes", "yes","no","no","no", "yes", "yes","no","yes","yes","no", "yes","yes","yes","yes","no","yes","yes" ))
```

Current output

```
-output:

   id a   b
  1 1 yes
  1 1 yes
  1 1  no
  1 1  no
  2 1  no
  2 2 yes
  2 1 yes
  3 1  no
  3 2 yes
  3 2 yes
  3 1  no
  4 1 yes
  4 1 yes
  4 2 yes
  5 1 yes
  5 1 yes
  5 1 no
  5 1 yes
  5 2 yes
```

The output should be:

```
   id a   b
  1 1 yes
  1 1 yes
  1 1  no
  1 1  no
  3 2 yes
  3 2 yes
  3 1  no
  4 1 yes
  4 1 yes
  4 2 yes
```

Current code attempt:

```r
data1 <- data %>% group_by(id) %>%
  filter(any(with(rle(b == 'yes'), lengths[values] > 1)) ) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

but I can't get the desired output.
anyone, please help me????????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following:

```r
library(dplyr)

data<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,1, 1,2,2,2,3,3,3, 3,4,4,4), a=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2),
                 b=c("yes", "yes","no","no","no", "yes", "yes","no","yes","yes","no", "yes","yes","yes"))


data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  # create indicators for two consecutive 'yes'
  mutate(prev_b = lag(b, 1),
         two_yes = b == 'yes' & prev_b == 'yes') %>%
  # create indicators for starting 'no'
  mutate(ones = 1,
         position = cumsum(ones),
         prev_no = cumsum(ifelse(b == 'no', 1, 0)),
         leading_no = position == prev_no) %>%
  # create indicator for final record
  mutate(next_b = lead(b, 1),
         last_record = is.na(next_b)) %>%
  # combine indicators at group level
  mutate(group_end_two_yes = any(two_yes & last_record),
         group_leading_no = any(leading_no)) %>%
  # drop
  mutate(drop_group = group_end_two_yes & group_leading_no) %>%
  filter(!drop_group,
         !leading_no) %>%
  # select initial columns
  select(id, a, b)
```

Comment: Thank you @Simon.S.A. The code is highly helpful but it can't remove the case **(yes, no, yes, yes)** as I added from my data with group id 5. one main criterion is there must be at least one observation after two consecutive **yes**.

Comment: You should be able to add something yourself before the filter. Probably something like `mutate(two_yes_at_end = any(two_yes & last_record))` then filter on it.